# Prove the Contraction Mapping Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, fixed-point-theorems

Prove the Contraction Mapping Theorem.

> Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space and $g : X \rightarrow X$ be a map such that $\forall x,y \in X, d(g(x), g(y)) \le \lambda d(x,y)$ for some $0<\lambda  < 1$. Then $g$ has a unique fixed point $x^* \in X $, and it attracts everything, i.e. for any $x_0 \in X$ , the sequence of iterates $x_0, g(x_0), g(g(x_0))$, ... converges to the fixed point $x^* \in X$.

The hint I am given are for existence and convergence - prove that the sequence is Cauchy. For uniqueness, choose two fixed points of $g$ and apply the map to both.

Still a bit do not know how to proceed after looking at the hint. Could anyone help me based on those hints?

Comment: Hint: $d(x_{n+1},x_n)=d(g(x_n),x_n)=d(g(g(x_{n-1})),g(x_{n-1}))\le \lambda d(g(x_{n-1}),x_{n-1})=d(x_n,x_{n-1})$

Comment: @TooOldForMath: what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I am giving you a hint so you can solve it. This is how it goes. Repeating what I wrote gives you $d(x_{n+1},x_n)\le \lambda^n d(x_1,x_0)$. Now $\lambda$ is between $0$ and $1$, so what happens when $n\rightarrow\infty$...?

Comment: why $\lambda d(g(x_{n-1}), x_{n-1}) = d(x_n, x_{n-1})$?

Comment: It is a typo.. sorry :D. There is a $\lambda$ missing.

Comment: How did you get $d(x_{n+1}, x_n) \le \lambda^n d(x_1, x_0)$? 

I only got $d(x_{n+1}, x_n) \le \lambda d(x_n, x_{n-1})$

, $d(x_{n}, x_{n-1}) \le \lambda d(x_{n-1}, x_{n-2})$

...$d(x_{2}, x_{1}) \le \lambda d(x_{1}, x_{0})$

How do you make the connection among my observation ... or there is an easier way to see it?

Assuming your assumption is right, does $\lambda^n$ as n approaches infinity  will become zero...so the right hand size is zero...which forces the left hand side to be 0?

Comment: $d(x_{n+1},x_n)\le \lambda d(x_n,x_{n-1}) \le \lambda^2 d(x_{n-1},x_{n-2})\le\cdots\le \lambda^n d(x_1,x_0)$

Comment: thanks...Based on  $d(x_{n+1}, x_n) \le \lambda^n d(x_1, x_0), $ does $\lambda^n$ as n approaches infinity will become zero...so the right hand size is zero...which forces the left hand side to be 0?..this shows that it is Cauchy right?

Comment: No not yet, for Cauchy you need to show $d(x_m,x_n)\rightarrow 0$ for $m,n\rightarrow\infty$. But for that you can use the triangle inequality as $d(x_m,x_n)\le d(x_m,x_{m-1})+d(x_{m-1},x_{m-2})+\cdots+d(x_{n+1},x_n)$ and then use our estimate (I assumed $m>n$)

Comment: we just shows that as n goes to infinity, the right hand side goes to zero ...so $d(x_{n+1}, x_n)$ will go to zero right?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: But this is not the proof for Cauchy? How are they different since the difference between two points are zero?

Comment: I really gave you everything you need. If you can't figure it out, just look it up in a random analysis book, it's for sure contained in every one of them.

Comment: After we got to $d(x_{n+1}, x_n) \le \lambda^n d(x_1, x_0)$, 

then assuming that $m > n$, $d(x_m, x_n) \le d(x_m, x_{m-1}) + d(x_{m-1}, x_{m-2}) + ... + d(x_{n+1}, x_{n})$ since each term of the right hand side is 0 ...so if we add up all the 0 terms, we get 0 on the right hand side. Therefore, $d(x_m, x_n)$ is 0. If this is right, then the question I have here is how do I guarantee that $x_{m-1} > x_n$?

Comment: No, you cannot argue like that, since the difference $m-n$ may also go to infinity. You need to sum the terms on the right side and use the estimate $d(x_{n+1},x_n)\le \lambda^n d(x_1,x_0)$ for each of them.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific for "to sum the terms on the right side and use the estimate $d(x_{n+1}, x_n) \le \lambda d(x_1, x,_0)$ for each of them" by giving an example or something since my approaches is to apply $d(x_{n+1}, x_n) \le \lambda d(x_1, x,_0)$ to each term on the right hand side, then add up all those zeros

Comment: I will answer the question in detail below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From

$$d(x_{n+1},x_n)=d(g(g(x_{n-1})),g(x_{n-1}))\le \lambda d(g(x_{n-1}), x_{n-1})=d(x_n,x_{n-1})$$

we get after $n$ applications of that inequality

$$d(x_{n+1},x_n)\le \lambda d(x_n,x_{n-1}) \le \lambda^2 d(x_{n-1},x_{n-2}) \le \cdots\le \lambda^n d(x_1,x_0)\tag{1}$$

Now we want to show that $(x_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. So let $\epsilon>0$.

We assume $x_1\not=x_0$ (otherwise $x_0$ is already a fixed point). Set $c=d(x_1,x_0)>0$.

Since $0<\lambda<1$, the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lambda^n$ converges (to $1/(1-\lambda)$). Therefore we can pick $N$ large enough such that

$$\sum_{k=n}^\infty \lambda^k<\frac{\epsilon}{c}$$

for all $n\ge N$.

Then for $m>n\ge N$ we have by the triangle inequality

$$d(x_m,x_n)\le \sum_{k=n}^{m-1} d(x_{k},x_{k+1})$$

Applying $(1)$ we obtain

$$d(x_m,x_n)\le c\sum_{k=n}^{m-1} \lambda^k\le c\sum_{k=n}^\infty \lambda^k<c\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{c}=\epsilon$$

So $(x_n)_n$ really is a Cauchy sequence. Since $(X,d)$ is complete, it converges to a limit $x\in X$.

By the equation $x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$, the limit satisfies $x=g(x)$, so it is a fixed point.

Uniqueness is trivial, let $y$ be another fixed point of $g$. Then

$$d(x,y)=d(g(x),g(y))\le \lambda d(x,y)$$

If now $x\not=y$, then $d(x,y)>0$, so we can divide by $d(x,y)$ to obtain $\lambda\ge 1$, a contradiction. Therefore, $x=y$.

Comment: "Therefore we can pick $N$ large enough such that

$$\sum_{k=n}^\infty \lambda^k<\frac{\epsilon}{c}$$

for all $n\ge N$."

For this part, do you backfill $$\frac{\epsilon}{c}$$ after going through the following:

"Then for $m>n\ge N$ we have by the triangle inequality

$$d(x_m,x_n)\le \sum_{k=n}^{m-1} d(x_{k},x_{k+1})$$

Applying $(1)$ we obtain

$$d(x_m,x_n)\le c\sum_{k=n}^{m-1} \lambda^k\le c\sum_{k=n}^\infty \lambda^k<c\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{c}=\epsilon$$"?

Comment: Backfill?  What are you talking about? This is a logically complete argument.

Comment: I just mean whether we get to go through the following part: "Then for $m>n\ge N$ we have by the triangle inequality

$$d(x_m,x_n)\le \sum_{k=n}^{m-1} d(x_{k},x_{k+1})$$

Applying $(1)$ we obtain

$$d(x_m,x_n)\le c\sum_{k=n}^{m-1} \lambda^k\le c\sum_{k=n}^\infty \lambda^k<c\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{c}=\epsilon$$" before filling $$\frac{\epsilon}{c}$$ in the "Therefore we can pick $N$ large enough such that

$$\sum_{k=n}^\infty \lambda^k<\frac{\epsilon}{c}$$ If not, how did you get $$\sum_{k=n}^\infty \lambda^k<\frac{\epsilon}{c}$$?

Comment: Please stop copying all this stuff in the comments. It makes it really unreadable. You are not "filling" $\epsilon/c$ whatever you mean by that. The logic is like this: $c$ is a constant defined as $d(x_1,x_0)$. It is fixed. Now I **throw you** an $\epsilon>0$ in the beginning. And now you notice, aha, the sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lambda^k$ converges therefore sequence of truncated sums $\sum_{k=n}^\infty \lambda^k$ converges to $0$ for $n\rightarrow\infty$. So it will eventually be smaller than **that given** $\epsilon/c$. Let us say that the point when it becomes smaller is reached at $N$

Comment: $\sum_{k=n}^\infty \lambda^k <\epsilon/c$ for all $n$ bigger than $N$.

Comment: how does Since $0<\lambda<1$, the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lambda^n$ converges (to $1/(1-\lambda)$), as I know this is a geometric series, come into the picture?

Comment: As I said, the series converges and yes, correct, that is because it is a geometric series. And now that means that the sequence $(\sum_{k=n}^\infty \lambda^k)_n$ converges to $0$. What do you not understand?

Comment: For the uniqueness part, how do you know $d(x,y)=d(g(x),g(y))$?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are fixed points, so $x=g(x)$ and $y=g(y)$.

Answer (score 0):

One proviso: You do need that $X$ is non-empty in the statement.

To elaborate on the hints you have been given;
To prove existance, pick $x_0 \in X$, and call (for convenience of writing) $g(x_0) = x_1, g(x_1) = x_2$ etcetera. Let $d(x_0,x_1) = d$. Then $d(x_1,x_2) \leq \lambda d$, and $d(x_2,x_3) \leq \lambda^2 d$...can you see how to extend this to show that the sequence is Cauchy?

For uniqueness, suppose $x$ and $y$ are both fixed points. What is $d(g(x),g(y))$?.

Comment: I don't think you do - if $x = y$ then both sides of the inequality are $0$, which is fine.

Comment: Touche! (I'm used to strong inequalities being used, which isn't really different here, and didn't notice the difference.)

Comment: @meta: After we got to $d(x_{n+1}, x_n) \le \lambda^n d(x_1, x_0)$, 

then assuming that $m > n$, $d(x_m, x_n) \le d(x_m, x_{m-1}) + d(x_{m-1}, x_{m-2}) + ... + d(x_{n+1}, x_{n})$ since each term of the right hand side is 0 ...so if we add up all the 0 terms, we get 0 on the right hand side. Therefore, $d(x_m, x_n)$ is 0. If this is right, then the question I have here is how do I guarantee that $x_{m-1} > x_n$?